# SSRS Hierarchy Recursive total by Row/Column

Tags: sql, recursion, matrix, reporting-services

I've created a very simple employee hierarchy in a matrix, looks something like:

```
                                      Buildings
                     -------------------------------------------------
Employee             |    One   |   Two   |   R2D2    |    Three    |     
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Miss Piggy           |    15    |         |           |             |
    Walter Muppet    |          |   50    |           |             |
    80's robot       |          |         |   2       |             |
    Andy Pig         |          |         |           |     2       |
        Randy Pig    |          |         |           |     1       |
    Animal Muppet    |    15    |   50    |   3       |             |
        ...
           ...
```

The SQL is a [recursive cte](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), returns: EmployeeName, ReportsToID, GroupLevel, Building, EmployeeID.  In the matrix I have the employee column with [these](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255243.aspx) settings to create the hierarchy grouping.  To get the count of employees by building in the matrix I have this expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!GroupLevel.Value="0",
        IIF(InScope("Building"), 
            IIF(InScope("EmployeeName"),sum(Fields!Count.Value, "Building", Recursive),""),""),
                IIF(Fields!GroupLevel.Value,Sum(Fields!Count.Value, "EmployeeName", recursive),""))
```

And so on, you can expand the hierarchy until there are no more managers.  The count is the sum of all the direct and indirect reports in that sit in the respective building.  etc.

**What I want is to have the total of all employees in all buildings for each manager.**
I can add row/column totals to get the sum for Miss Piggy, however I also want totals for all buildings for the other managers.  Meaning Miss Piggy has people that sit in Buildings: Two, R2D2 and three.  Animal Muppet has people that sit in Buildings: One, Two and Three.

Ideally I would like the report to look like this.

```
                                      Buildings
                     -------------------------------------------------
Employee             |    One   |   Two   |   R2D2    |    Three    |     
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Miss Piggy           |    15    |   100   |   5       |     6       |
    Walter Muppet    |          |   50    |           |             |
    80's robot       |          |         |   2       |             |
    Andy Pig         |          |         |           |     2       |
        Randy Pig    |          |         |           |     1       |
    Animal Muppet    |    15    |   50    |           |     3       |
        ...          |          |         |           |     2       |                  
           ...       |          |         |   1       |             |
```

Any ideas how to accomplish?

Comment: Why don't you add a column group on building, that way you would only need two row groups and one column group. If your column group is based on Building then you could simply add a =COUNT(EmployeeID).

Comment: @lrb5 Not sure I follow.  Wouldn't that return the sum for all buildings for the respective manager?  I need it by each building for each manager.

Comment: My thinking was that you are grouping by ReportsToID and EmployeeID row-wise. If you are then could you add a group header for the ReportsToID and EmployeeID and hide the details so that in your column groups, now based in the column headers, you could aggregate the count based on all items in the group? I may be way off and if so I apologize in advance.

Comment: @lrb Because this is a hierarchy I went with a [recursive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) query to know who reports to who. User picks the manager and it returns all direct and indirect reports until there is no more. There is a row/column group based on the matrix table.  The indentation and drill down of the ReportsToID to EmployeeID is done like [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255243.aspx).  Is there another approach that would work better?